# Django form "passwords do not match" but they do

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Initially, I struggled with template rendering but now I can't fix the validation error. It does not matter what input I give, it shows error even if I enter **a** in both fields.

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="register-form">
        <form method='post'> 
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="register-field">
                    {{field}}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <p>{{ form.password.errors.as_text }}</p>
            <button id="register-button" type='submit' value='Save'>Register</button>
            <button id="already-registered" action="{% url 'home' %}">Already registered?</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock  %}}
```

forms.py:

```
def clean_password(self):
    """checks users passwords match in form and renders error if not"""
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
    if password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match.")

    return password
```

Comment: You need to write this in `def clean`, since the order of "cleaning" can be regarded as "unspecified", and thus it is possible that the `confirm_password` is not yeat cleaned.

Comment: ahh ok thank you will try. I did see this in the docs but struggled to translate it. will rename the clean password func to clean then and go from there. appreciate your help.